# Closure equal to derived set

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis

If we assume that $A$ is open then my book gives $cl(A)=A′$ (without proof)

My idea was to use the definition $cl(A)=A∪A′$, which would give us our first inclusion.

I have no idea how to prove the second inclusion.

I would like to add that I find this result very strange since if we take $A=(0,1)$ we'll have $cl(A)=[1,0]$ whereas $A'={0,1}$ (I can't see how the points in $A$ are limitpoints themselves)

Also for my last and maybe most important question, my book defines 'limit points' and 'closure points' of sets. What is the difference?

Comment: Do you mean: "if $A$ is closed"? Or are we dealing with a discrete topology or something? What is $A'$?

Comment: I believe that the problem was formulated the way I said, but it might be a messup on their part.. would it be true if $A$ was closed?

Comment: If $A'$ is the set of limit points, then I can see it being true. Anything in $[0,1]$ is a limit point of $(0,1)$. $\{0,1\}$ is just the boundary. I'm not certain what "derived set means".

Comment: The derived set is A'

Comment: Limit points and closure points can be defined differently in different books. Can you identify your book or type the definitions it gives?

Comment: Yes, but what is its definition, specifically?

Comment: Ok. According to the definition on Wikipedia, the derived set is the set of limit points. So yes, the closure of an open set is the derived set. Try this: take an $x\in A\cup A'$ and checks cases. You'll see it needs to be in an open set fully contained in $A$ or it is on the boundary. That should do it.

Comment: A Course in Mathematical Analysis by D.J.H. Garling, I don't have my book at hand right now. But I'll try and give the definitions as soon as I'm home

Comment: not true for discrete spaces where $A'=\emptyset$ for every $A$ (but $cl(A)\not=\emptyset$). This holds no matter what we assume about $A$ (open, closed, etc.) @jdods An isolated singleton is not a limit point.

Comment: @jdods, but that's the thing; I don't see how an $x∈A$ is a limit point.

Comment: It's the limit of the sequence $x,x,x,...$ isn't it? Any open set containing $x$ will intersect $A$.

Comment: @jdods a limit point is not the same as the limit of a sequence (confusing terminology perhaps). By definition, $x$ is a limit point of $A$ if every neighborhood $U$ of $x$ contains at least one point of $A$ *different from* $x$. (In Hausdorff spaces this implies that every neighborhood $U$ of $x$ contains infinitely many points of $A$ *different from* $x$.) If $x$ is isolated, (i.e. if $\{x\}$ is open) then $U=\{x\}$ is a neighborhood if $x$ that contains no other points of $A$.

Comment: I don't understand your last comment @jdods, so I'm allowed to take the limit of the sequence $x,x,...$? As  limitpoint?

Comment: Don't use my last comment if the definition of limit point is as Mirko has given. As I asked initially, and Mirko had confirmed regarding discrete topology, maybe we need more context here to figure out the answer.

Comment: If $A=(0,1)$ in the usual topology of the reals, then $cl(A)=[0,1]=A'$. The result is true in general as long as $A$ has no isolated points. Note every neighborhood of $\frac12$ intersects points of $(0,1)$ different from $\frac12$. (And in some cases it is ok to use limits of sequences, e.g. in first countable Hausdorff spaces, and sequences that are not eventually constant, and $\frac12$ is the limit of $\frac12-\frac1n$ as $n\to\infty$.)

Comment: Since this is from a mathematical analysis book, I think we can conclude that we are working with the standard topology on $\mathbb R$. Mirko's detailed comments should help you solve this.